# Multi-Column Name Search MySQL

Tags: mysql, search, wildcard, where-clause

I am currently working on a live search and I need to be able to find parts of a name in two columns (we need to separate first and last name). I personally would like to keep the command short, however the only way I have been able to get this to work is:

**User Searches For**

```
John Doe
```

**Generated SQL Query**

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE
(first_name LIKE '%john%' OR last_name LIKE '%john%') AND
(last_name LIKE '%doe%' OR last_name LIKE '%doe%');
```

The search field is one box so I do some simple separation by space. Most cases this won't reach beyond three sets of clauses, was just wondering if there was any better way to do this.

**NOTE:**
I would like to be able to do partial matching. So I should be able to find John Doe if I look for "John Do"

**SOLUTION**
With the help of Rolando, I did however come up with a solution, posted for anyone else who finds this. Follow his instructions on how to create the index below, then run this:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE
(MATCH(first,last) AGAINST ('+john* +do*' IN BOOLEAN MODE))
```

Comment: Thank you for the vote of confidence !!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your best bet here is create a FULLTEXT index that encompasses the two fields

Step 1) Create a stop word file with just three word

echo "a" > /var/lib/mysql/stopwords.txt
echo "an" >> /var/lib/mysql/stopwords.txt
echo "the" >> /var/lib/mysql/stopwords.txt

Step 2) Add these options to /etc/my.cnf

ft_min_word_len=2
ft_stopword_file=/var/lib/mysql/stopwords.txt

Step 3) Create FULLTEXT index on the first and last name columns

ALTER TABLE users ADD FULLTEXT first_last_name_index (first,last);

Step 4) Implement the MATCH function in your search

Something Like This:

SELECT * FROM users WHERE (MATCH(first,last) AGAINST ('John' IN BOOLEAN MODE)) AND (MATCH(first,last) AGAINST ('Doe' IN BOOLEAN MODE));

[Click here to Learn More about FULLTEXT indexing](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html)

Comment: The application forces all searches to be over three words as it, however I knew about neither. Good tip. However I need to allow for partial matches as well.

Comment: However you lead me to create the solution above!